# Meaning of lattice gauge theories

Tags: condensed-matter, definition, gauge-invariance, lattice-gauge-theory

I would like to ask about the physical interpretation of lattice gauge theories. Coming from a condensed matter background, I know only that lattice gauge theories are constructed by adding additional degrees of freedom (gauge fields) in order to enforce a local symmetry. Then, the choice of a gauge amounts to the choice of a superselection sector, i.e., the choice of a sector of the Hilbert space specified by the value of the local charges (if the gauge theory is abelian, all of them can be diagonalized simultaneously).

I would like to take a step back and understand what these theories are built for (I have heard that they are used to construct models with topological order, such as the toric code) and if my definition of lattice gauge theory is correct, as far as condensed matter physics is concerned, or additional subtleties and ingredients are needed.

Comment: Maybe not the answer you're looking for. But continuum gauge theories certainly exist and the lattice is a valid regulator for them.